# Print length of longest sequence of consecutive numbers

Tags: java, array

Problem H (Longest Natural Successors):

> Two consecutive integers are natural successors if the second is the
>   successor of the first in the sequence of natural numbers (1 and 2 are
>   natural successors). Write a program that reads a number N followed by
>   N integers, and then prints the length of the longest sequence of
>   consecutive natural successors.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> Input  7 2 3 5 6 7 9 10
> Output 3
> ```

This is my code so far:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;


    public class Conse {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
     int x=scan.nextInt();
     int[] array= new int[x];
     for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
         array[i]=scan.nextInt();
     System.out.println(array(array));
      }
public static int array(int[] array){
    int count=0,temp=0;
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        count=0;
        for(int j=i,k=i+1;j<array.length-1;j++,k++)
            if(array[j]-array[k]==1)
                count++;
            else{if(temp<count)
                temp=count;
            break;}
        }
    return temp+1;
 } 

  }
```

Comment: Would be interesting to try solving this question using LINQ.

Answer (score 5):

Using `static` for the `consecutive()` function is appropriate.  However, the omission of braces, the inconsistent indentation, and lack of spaces between operators is just as bad as [before](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/71285/9357).

Your function crashes on arrays of length 0 or 1.

The variable names `f` and `counter` could be improved.  I think that a different looping structure would be clearer as well.

```
public static int consecutive(int[] array) {
    if (array.length <= 1) {
        return array.length;
    }

    int maxRun = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        int thisRun = 1;
        while (i < array.length && array[i - 1] + 1 == array[i]) {
            thisRun++;
            i++;
        }
        if (maxRun < thisRun) {
            maxRun = thisRun;
        }
    }
    return maxRun;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Naming**

- a class named `Conse` does not express what the class is about.
- a method named `array` does not epress what the method is about.

For naming classes you should use noun or noun phrases. For naming methods you should use verbs or verb phrases.

**Logic**

Consider to change your logic to use only one loop. On each iteration check if the current number equals the `lastnumber + 1`. If yes, increment the counter by `1` if no set the counter `= 1`.

After these checks set the lastnumber to the current number and calculate the maximum of the current counter and the overall maximum counter.

```
private static int getLongestSuccessorCount(int[] input) {
    int length = input.length;
    if (length <= 1) {
        return length;
    }

    int counter = 0;
    int lastNumber = 0;
    int longestSuccessorCount = 0;
    for (int currentNumber : input) {

        if (currentNumber == lastNumber + 1) {
            counter += 1;
        } else {
            counter = 1;
        }

        lastNumber = currentNumber;
        longestSuccessorCount = Math.max(longestSuccessorCount, counter);
    }
    return longestSuccessorCount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few generic comments:

1. CheckStyles. (have spaces, line spaces, if-else/for-do-while block) proper.
2. Nomenclature (Class Conse, function name array, a return variable temp)

Comments related to the code snippet:

1. Invalid value of x (if x is zero or negative, would this work:

   ```
   int[] array= new int[x];
   ```
2. Two loops is not required. One traversal is enough because all you need to do is check the consecutiveness and if it fails update the max.

   ```
   public static int getConsecutiveness(int[] input){
       int maxCount = 1;
       int tempMax=1;
       for(int i=1;i<input.length;i++){
           if(input[i]-input[i-1]==1){
               tempMax++;
           }else{
               maxCount=Math.max(maxCount, tempMax);
               tempMax=1;
           }
       }
       maxCount=Math.max(maxCount, tempMax);
       return maxCount;
   }
   ```

Comment: To post code you need to either add 4 spaces before each line , or you select all of the code and click on `{}`.

Comment: Had some issue with it. Tried to correct the same.